# How do I find duplicate integers in a List<int> and remove ONE of them?

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

Beginner; novice-level problem. Here is the code that generates 30 random numbers, sorts them in ascending order, and then sorts them in descending order.  The last objective is to find duplicates in the list and remove one of them (e.g., if there are two 27's, I want to remove one and leave the other).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random randomNum = new Random();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i += 1)
            numbers.Add(randomNum.Next(1, 100));

        Console.Write("List of random numbers:");
        foreach (var number in numbers)
            Console.Write(" {0} ", number);

        var sorted =
            from number in numbers
            orderby number
            select number;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("List in ascending order:");
        foreach (var element in sorted)
            Console.Write(" {0} ", element);

        var sortdescending =
            from number in numbers
            orderby number descending
            select number;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("List in descending order:");
        foreach (var element in sortdescending)
            Console.Write(" {0} ", element);
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Side note: "remove one of them" and "remove all but one" are totally different questions. I'd be very surprised if assignment says "remove one".

Comment: What if there are three 27's? Remove one and leave two?

Comment: you might be a beginner but does that mean you can't use google ?

Answer (score 0):

`int` is buil-in type, then you can use simple:

```
numbers = numbers.Distinct();
```

but if you have class, you can then override two methods: **Equals** and **GetHashCode**

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to use

```
using System.Linq;
```

then (as Konrad said)

```
var distinctNumbers = numbers.Distinct();
```

Comment: Sorry the question was unclear.  You are right: no matter how many instances of x there are, I only want one displayed in the final list. The solution involving numbers.Distinct() sounds helpful, but I don't know how to use it in the code.  I wish I was smarter, but I'm not, that's why I'm asking questions.  I've been on Google, etc., since 9:30 this morning, consulted textbooks, watched instructional videos, emailed a coder acquaintance...would really appreciate any help you might be willing to offer.

Comment: @user3500004, then edit your question to be more clear and allow to remove downvotes from those correct answers.

Comment: I have a list of random numbers.  They've been sorted, now I want to find and remove the duplicates from the list.  I don't know how to do that.  var distinctNumbers = numbers.Distinct(); may very well be the key to this, but I don't know how to put that into lines of code that will eliminate the duplicates.